# Android Layout - Can't Get buttons and text to display

Tags: android, layout

I'm having an issue here, I'm unfamiliar with layouts on android and I can't get this layout to do as I wish.

I would like it to appear as follows:

```
[Button][Button]
Text Filled Here
Text Filled Here
Text Filled Here
Text Filled Here
Text Filled Here
```

The TextView is populated via my messagehelper that sends the text to the UI

Eventually my code will be iterating through a list of objects retrieved from a web service and displaying them all on their own rows, with an option to press one and view it on a map.

At the moment, I can only get either the two buttons OR the text to show separately, or all three of them on the same line, not the two buttons on the first line and the text populated downwards!!

Here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/buttonLayout" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/vehicleButton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Refresh"
        android:onClick="getVehicles" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/logoutButton"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Logout"
        android:onClick="logout" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/textLayout" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: give your linear layout android:orientation="vertical"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `LinearLayout` orientation is `horizontal`, you need to change the 1st and 3rd `LinearLayout` orientation on your `xml` to `vertical`.

use `android:orientation="vertical"`

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your layout:

EDIT: If by "populated downwards" mean you want text below the buttons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/vehicleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="getVehicles"
        android:text="Refresh" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/logoutButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/vehicleButton"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/vehicleButton"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:onClick="logout"
        android:text="Logout" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
        android:layout_below="@id/vehicleButton"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: OP want `TextViews` to be populated downwards.

Comment: What does "populated downwards" mean? Below the buttons?

Comment: It will be filled via a messagehelper class that will pass text to the UI.

Answer (score 0):

In order to place textview bottom of each other use orientation as vertical.

And Code will be This

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/buttonLayout" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/vehicleButton"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Refresh"
    android:onClick="getVehicles" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/logoutButton"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="Logout"
    android:onClick="logout" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textLayout" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"

>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

</LinearLayout>
```